# Sign up with email verification does not create a session token when user get's redirected to web app after clicking the verification link

Tags: parse-platform

According to Parse js guide:

> The `Parse.User` obtained from `Parse.User.current()` will always be authenticated. If you need to check if a `Parse.User` is authenticated,
>   you can invoke the `authenticated` method. You do not need to check
>   authenticated with `Parse.User` objects that are obtained via an
>   authenticated method.

So when a user Signs up on my web app, get's a verification email which after clicking will direct the user back to the app. Then I call `Parse.User.current()` which returns the user object but the sessionToken it's empty. The user object looks like this:

```
ACL: {*: {…}, vIl61voP42: {…}}
createdAt: "2019-11-08T11:47:44.102Z"
emailVerified: true
objectId: "vIl61voP42"
origin: "Web App"
sessionToken: undefined
updatedAt: "2019-11-08T11:50:19.633Z"
username: "dfgg@dfgg.com"
```

My goal would be to allow the user to access the app without having to manually login and therefor create a session. From Parse docs my understanding was that once we have a user returned from `Parse.User.current()` would mean this user would be logged in and therefor I could set and save new data into the user object, which is not the case...

For sign up I've a standard Parse sign up as per documentation:

```js
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", "my name");
user.set("password", "my pass");
user.set("email", "email@example.com");

try {
  await user.signUp();
  // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
} catch (error) {
  // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
  alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
}
```

Once sign up form it's submitted the user receives a email confirmation link which will redirect them to my application `url`. This is how my Parse server settings looks like:

```js
const api = new ParseServer ({
  ...

  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 0,
  preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: true,
  customPages: {
    // App
    passwordResetSuccess: settings["appUrl"] + "/login",
    verifyEmailSuccess: settings["appUrl"] + "/dashboard",
    linkSendSuccess: settings["appUrl"] + "/email-confirmation",
    // Parse
    invalidLink: settings["serverUrl"] + "/expired",
    choosePassword: settings["serverUrl"] + "/choose_password"
  }

  ...
})
```

Finally, once the user arrives at my `dashboard` route from the verification email link I get the current user via `await Parse.User.current()` which returns me the user object without a session token. Also checked on my local dev db and there's no session being created.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share some code so we can advise? Have you tried to call `await user.fetch()` in order to update the session token?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I've updated my question with more code and details. using `user.fetch()` makes the field `sessionToken` to go from `undefined` to not existing at all inside the user object. I use `user.toJSON()` to get the user object and inspect it's values. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, is this code running on the client side (web browser) or server side (node.js)?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo this is all using the Parse JS SDK for the client side, excluding the parseServer config which lives on the server. So resuming, in your experience, when a user clicks on the verification link and lands on my application, calling the `Parse.User.current()` should have the session token, correct? By the way I'm using parse-server 2.4.8

Comment: @DaviMacêdo sorry, parse-server 2.8.4

Comment: I don't think so. Unfortunatelly I think you will have to log in the user again.